# I had created a login page, but whenever i enter credentials it shows me NoReverseMatch at /login

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

my html login page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/login">
{% csrf_token %}
<table width="20%" bgcolor="0099CC" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan=2><center><font size=4><b>User Login Page</b></font></center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<!-- name=Username to username -->
<td><input type="text" size=25 name="username"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<!-- name=Password to password-->
<td><input type="Password" size=25 name="password"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<div> 
{% for messages in messages %}
<h3> {{messages}}  </h3>
{% endfor %}
</div>

</body>
</html>



my views file is:



from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

  def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST.get('username', None)
      password = request.POST.get('password', None)

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.info(request,'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login ')
  else:
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

my URLs for views are :

```
  from Django.urls import path

  from. import views

  urlpatterns = [
     path('',views.homepage, name='homepage'),
     path('login',views.login, name='login'),
     path('registration',views.registration, name='registration'),
  ]
```

Error shown :

```
  NoReverseMatch at /login
  Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
  Request Method:   POST
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
  Django Version:   3.0.4
  Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
  Exception Value:  
  Reverse for 'login ' not found. 'login ' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
  Exception Location:   C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in 
  _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
  Python Executable:    C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
  Python Version:   3.8.1
  Python Path:  
  ['C:\\Users\\siddh\\projects\\telusko',
  'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python38.zip',
  'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs',
  'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib',
  'C:\\Program Files\\Python38',
  'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
   Server time: Fri, 8 May 2020 14:27:05 +0000
```

please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error please help me to solve this error

Comment: If you look at the error message, there's a space in `'login '` that shouldn't be there. Change your view to use `return redirect('login ')`. Note that Django comes with a [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView), it would be simpler to use that than write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line of code or remove space from ('login ')

```
return redirect('login ')
```

replace with this line of code

```
return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
**redirect(reverse('login'))** in place of **redirect('login')**
 you can import reverse using below line.

```
from django.urls import reverse
```